# What are these figures for?

Tags: image, qr-code

I found this figure on a web page : [image]

What are they called , how to use them and what are they usefull ?

Comment: See [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code): "The QR Code system has become popular [..] due to its fast readability and greater storage capacity compared to standard [..] barcodes. Applications include product tracking, item identification, time tracking, document management, general marketing, and much more." (There is also a section on usages as [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#URLs)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called QR codes.
You can get an app to your phone and read them with the camera.

They are used mostly to direct a user onto a webpage.

Comment: how to get the app by the qr code ?

Comment: if you have an Android/WinPhone/iPhone you go to the appropriate App store and search for qr reader

Answer (score 2):

[qr code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)

They can be scanned from images by devices such as cell phone cameras and could link to a web page for example.

I do not understand why one would be on a web page however, where you can just click: their most common use is on paper publicity seen on the streets.